# How to retrieve my Install Statistics from the Google Developer's Console

Tags: json, google-analytics, google-api, reporting, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to programmatically retrieve my company's app data from the Google Developer's Console, specifically the daily installs. I have found that Google recommends the gsutil tool to access the data programmatically through the Google Cloud Storage SDK. However, I beleive they charge for this service. I want a free way to programmatically retrieve the data, preferably as a JSON stream to avoid dealing with file downloads. I have found the "direct reporting" links, but I have problems authenticating when I try to use them, and I also have to do something with the actual files then.

Is there a way to get a JSON version of the data through OAuth2 or something without downloading an Excel file? Has anyone had to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the gsutil tool to access the company's storage bucket that are provided by google is a free service. I wrote a code that will run the gsutil code as a process through the command line and parsed the downloaded .csv files into a database for storage. OAuth2 was not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into use the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/).

There are [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) available in a number of languages.

You should work through the [Hello Analytics APIs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/installed-py) to get started.

[Java Script](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js)
[PHP](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php)
[Python](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py)
[Java](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java)

A quick solution for building a dashboard would also be the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/).

Comment: I looked into it and it is not exactly what I am aiming for. I am not after the Google Analyitcs information, but rather the Google Developer's Console information. I also need to programmatically put the data into a database, and I know that The cloud storage offered by Google has methods of doing what I need, but I was looking for womeone with that specific experience to guide me. Thank you though!